# iTunes connect creation of app won't load

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have registered my bundle id, and Im now trying to create leader boards for my app. So I go to iTunes connect -manage apps - create app. I entered in all the information and then click continue. Then the page won't load, my app isn't created, and I get the following error after ~5 min
Gateway Timeout

The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this trouble with iTunes Connect in the past. It seems it's just a bad connection (server side) and usually resolves itself reasonably quickly (max about 24 hours). Just keep trying.